# CorsOrigin Error in Java spring boot to access All Origin not Specific Origin

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cors, cross-domain

I have a Java spring boot Backend Code in which i have made some API in crud operations and i run my code a sub domain and wanted to use the API in some frontend application but iam getting corsOrigin error,

the Below code works in the particular origin only which is localhost:3000,

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class CorsConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer  {

        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
            .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS")
                    .allowedHeaders("*")
                    .allowedHeaders("*")
                    .allowCredentials(true);
        }
```

I have also tried doing this to access all origin but failed in the below code

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class CorsConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer  {

        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedOrigins("*")
            .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS")
                    .allowedHeaders("*")
                    .allowedHeaders("*")
                    .allowCredentials(true);
        }
```

I want to make the code to be accessed by all the origin from the front end application ,

example: localhost:3000,localhost:4200,localhost:9000 and etc
please provide me a better solution and thanks in advance..

Answer (score -2):

Handling CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) with an aspect in Spring Boot involves creating an aspect that intercepts requests and applies CORS headers based on certain conditions. Here's an example of how you can achieve this:

1. Create a new aspect class that will handle CORS:

```java
@Aspect
@Component
public class CorsAspect {

    @Before("execution(* com.example.*.*Controller.*(..))")
    public void before(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        HttpServletResponse response = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getResponse();
        if (response != null) {
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, we are using an aspect to intercept requests to all controller methods in the com.example package. The before method sets the CORS headers on the HttpServletResponse object.

2. Enable aspect auto-proxying in your Spring Boot configuration:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class AppConfig {
    // Other configurations
}
```

By enabling aspect auto-proxying, Spring Boot will automatically apply the CORS aspect to the appropriate controller methods.

Using an aspect to handle CORS in Spring Boot allows you to define the CORS behavior in a single place and apply it to multiple controller methods. However, it's important to note that using a global CORS configuration as shown in the previous response is the recommended approach in Spring Boot, as it provides a more centralized and maintainable solution for handling CORS.

Comment: "Manually" re-implementing CORS is almost always a bad solution, simply because it's error-prone; CORS is indeed more complex than meets the eye. You're better relying on an existing CORS middleware. Spring Boot has one, although I won't comment here on whether it's well-designed.

Comment: hey can you send me anything related to the exisiting CORS middleware in other link or website that is can work on

Comment: I dont understand why did you give me negative point to my solution? use aspect for such issues with crosscutting behavior  is recommended by spring framework?!!